# Show all Dates between 2 Date fields from same table MYSQL 5.5

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains: Id, Name, Startdate, Enddate. I would like to Find all days between Startdate and Enddate within current month.

User Alden starts in january and ends in february but need to show only the current month ( here i mentioned current month as january)

| ID | Name | Startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Justin | 01-01-2024 | 10-01-2024 |
| 2 | Elena | 10-02-2024 | 20-02-2024 |
| 3 | Alden | 20-01-2024 | 20-02-2024 |

Output Result Expected to show all days between starting and enddate in current month.

| Name | Days |
| --- | --- |
| justin | 01-01-2024 |
| justin | 02-01-2024 |
| justin | 03-01-2024 |
| justin | 04-01-2024 |
| justin | 05-01-2024 |
| justin | 06-01-2024 |
| justin | 07-01-2024 |
| justin | 08-01-2024 |
| justin | 09-01-2024 |
| justin | 10-01-2024 |
| Alden | 20-01-2024 |
| Alden | 21-01-2024 |
| Alden | 22-01-2024 |
| Alden | 23-01-2024 |
| Alden | 24-01-2024 |
| Alden | 25-01-2024 |
| Alden | 26-01-2024 |
| Alden | 27-01-2024 |
| Alden | 28-01-2024 |
| Alden | 29-01-2024 |
| Alden | 30-01-2024 |
| Alden | 31-01-2024 |

Comment: Have you even tried anything? Please show your current attempt.

Comment: This is one of those things that is easily solvable with a date table. There's a lot of tutorials online for creating and filling one. Once created, this is just a simple INNER JOIN query to get your results.

Comment: Recursive CTE will solve.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a date range reference then join it with your table. To create that, you'll need to use `RECURSIVE cte` or if you're on older MySQL (below v8), you'll have to manually generate the date range using a few functions then make them as a derived table.

For `RECURSIVE cte`, you might end up with a query like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT '2024-01-01' AS mdate UNION ALL
  SELECT mdate + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM cte WHERE mdate + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= '2024-01-31')
SELECT *
  FROM cte JOIN mytable ON mdate BETWEEN Startdate AND Enddate
  ORDER BY ID, mdate;
```

And here's an example for the second option - older MySQL version:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT DATE_ADD('2024-01-01', INTERVAL (t1*t3)+t2 DAY) AS mdate
    FROM
    (SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) a 
       CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 0 t2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) b 
       CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 1 t3 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 
     UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) c
  GROUP BY mdate) md
JOIN mytable ON mdate BETWEEN Startdate AND Enddate
  WHERE MONTH(mdate)=1 /*specify the month*/
  ORDER BY ID, mdate;
```

[MySQL demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/gPGFMy1E)

Alternatively, if you're using MariaDB, then you can make use of it's sequence engine to create the date range:

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT DATE_ADD('2024-01-01', INTERVAL seq DAY) AS mdate
  FROM seq_0_to_30) 
SELECT *
  FROM cte JOIN mytable ON mdate BETWEEN Startdate AND Enddate
  ORDER BY ID, mdate;
```

[MariaDB demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/FaG1-I5B)

Comment: A little bounds adjustment can keep date as a datetype `DATE_ADD('2024-01-01', interval seq day) AS mdate FROM seq_0_to_30)`; [ref](https://dbfiddle.uk/xOYWWzkQ)

Comment: That's new to me @danblack ! As soon as I saw your comment, I went to test that to understand how it works and I can say I've been missing. I'll edit my answer to use that, thanks.

Comment: Just a small amount of my OCD avoiding treating dates and strings as equivalent (even though in many cases it just works).

Comment: @FanoFN Your sequence generation in the _"older MySQL version"_ is a little bit [_wonky_](https://dbfiddle.uk/XAiv2AZP) ;-)

Comment: Thanks @user1191247 . I'll revise the answer and do some correction.

Comment: You are still generating unnecessary duplicates and removing with GROUP BY - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tE3N7_Fy)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware but I won't change that query too much because that's how the query is written back when I'm still using older MySQL. Besides, OP didn't mention what version of MySQL they are using so, unless OP specifically want a more efficient older MySQL query than what I've provided, I just fix the specific part and make sure it's usable.